# What is the purpose of IApplicationBuilder.New()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

In the new ASP.NET 5.0 (vNext), the startup code relies on the [`IApplicationBuilder` interface](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/ed339a35d2a0ae6137c12e9bc8e8b037ed429bc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions/IApplicationBuilder.cs). The `Use` method is used to add a handler to the builder, while `Build` is used to construct the final delegate. But I can't figure out what is the purpose of [`New`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/ed339a35d2a0ae6137c12e9bc8e8b037ed429bc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions/IApplicationBuilder.cs#L19). I've been digging in GitHub, but can't find any place where that's used.

Anyone understand what is the purpose of that method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be there to branch [clone] the original instance (as can be demonstrated in [`src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/Extensions/MapExtensions.cs`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions/Extensions/MapExtensions.cs)). There was also a previous [`MapWhenExtensions.cs`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/335895d9b49042312eca12a089340adf3ca0a219/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/Extensions/MapWhenExtensions.cs), but it appears to have been removed from the dev branch.)

I suspect it's an artifact of a previous design that would provide the ability to bind middleware based on circumstances without affecting the root's configuration. The fact that it's been there since before `IBuilder` was refactored to `IApplicationBuilder` and that most dependencies were in files that have since been removed from the dev branch, I would venture a guess that it's old news.

Of course it's hard to tell given neither the interface nor the base [implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/ApplicationBuilder.cs#L72-L75) are commented.

Comment: `app.Map` still exists (and is **very unlikely** to be removed), but it's now part of the `Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions` package: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions/Extensions/MapExtensions.cs

Comment: @pinpoint: I'm aware however they're were a family of other `.Map*` methods that didn't make it (that also used this method).

Comment: Which `Map*` methods are you referring to, exactly? The only 'official' mapping extensions ever shipped back to the Katana era were `Map` and `MapWhen`: http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin/Mapping/

Comment: `MapWhen` is there: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions/Extensions/MapWhenExtensions.cs

Comment: I stand corrected then. When I broad the dev branch (when I answered this) it looked like MapWhen was absolved from the dev branch.

Answer (score 5):

`New()` creates a second `ApplicationBuilder`, sharing all the `ApplicationServices` and `ServerFeatures` of the first one, but none of the middleware. It is used internally by the branching extensions (`Map`, `MapWhen`, `UseWhen`) to create the new 'branch'.

You can find the implementation here: [ApplicationBuilder.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Internal/ApplicationBuilder.cs).

In some cases, it is also useful in higher-level frameworks.

For exemple, the `[MiddlewareFilter]` attribute in MVC Core uses `New()` internally to execute a piece of ASP.NET Core middleware inside the MVC framework (i.e. as a filter). MVC Core creates a small pipeline around the middleware, builds it into a RequestDelegate, then runs the HttpContext through it. Just like ASP.NET Core does with your 'main' pipeline built in `Startup.cs`.

Thanks to this feature, we can reuse a piece of general-purpose ASP.NET Core middleware, from inside MVC.

For more information, see [MiddlewareFilterBuilder.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/MiddlewareFilterBuilder.cs) in ASP.NET MVC Core.